# How do I test a webview extension I've created for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

By test I mean some kind of automated unit test. Manual testing takes too long.

Answer (score 0):

One can use VSCode Extension Tester https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/wiki/WebView